# Should I restart after a pacman upgrade?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, drivers, pacman

after running

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
```

or

```
sudo pacman -S [something to install]
```

should I restart just to be safe?

Comment: Note that `pacman -Syyu` should not be used as a regular means of upgrading as it forces a re-download of up-to-date databases, wasting the bandwidth of the mirrors. It's considered good etiquette to use `pacman -Syu` for upgrades instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way is to find what programs/services use the old libraries and restart them. And you can achieve it by listing all used files using 'lsof' and find those that have 'DEL' type. DEL means filename was removed from the filesystem but it is still stuck in memory because someone uses it.

Here is the full command line:

```
 sudo lsof +c 0 | grep 'DEL.*lib' | awk '1 { print $1 ": " $NF }' | sort -u
```

Comment: After generating that list of services and libraries, it still is not clear which systemd services need to be restarted. Hence, even though I know which processes and libs need a restart, it is typically non-trivial to determine which services to restart based on that list.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it really show the processes. It is easy to determine the unit (with some experience) to restart. Eventually one can even grep out the unit file somehow.

Answer (score 10):

If there are updates to the kernel, glibc or systemd, you may want to restart so the updated versions are in use. If you have, say, updates to your desktop environment, a simple logout/login is enough.

Answer (score 10):

The only mandatory reason to reboot is a new kernel (and you can soft-reboot using kexec). See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kexec for details, in short:

- load the new kernel, initramfs and specify the boot cmdline

  ```
  kexec -l /boot/new-kernel --initrd=/boot/new-initramfs --reuse-cmdline
  ```
- invoke `kexec` (use `systemctl` for proper shutdown, `kexec -e` would execute directly)

  ```
  systemctl kexec
  ```
- Note that if you create a `kexec-load@.service` as explained in the wiki, if you reboot, `systemd` will automatically soft-reboot using `kexec` instead of doing a bios reboot

Little bit improved version that gives systemd service names:

```
PIDS="(lsof +c0 -n 2> /dev/null | grep 'DEL.*lib' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u)"
for PID in $PIDS; do
    systemctl status $i
done | grep '●' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u
```

or one-line:

```
for i in $(lsof +c0 -n 2> /dev/null | grep 'DEL.*lib' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u); do systemctl status $i; done | grep '●' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u
```

Note that there are some issues:

- `systemctl daemon-reload` should be executed prior to restarting anything else
- if PID 1 (`systemd` itself) needs to be restarted, it can be done using `systemctl daemon-reexec`
- `systemctl restart dbus.service` breaks some other services, they need to be restarted after dbus restart:

  - `systemd` itself: `systemctl daemon-reexec`
  - `systemd-logind`
  - `systemd-machined`
  - probably other systemd-*/other services that (heavily) use `dbus`
- If you're connected via SSH and SSH needs to be restarted, but `systemctl restart sshd` won't restart it as long you are connected, I see 2 options:

  - schedule `systemctl restart sshd` using `at/cron/systemd` timers
  - restart `SSH` using another remote (secure) shell such as `mosh`
- running `screen/tmux` may also block services like `SSH` from restarting, the easiest way is to close these sessions before restarting services
- as told in a previous answer, logout/login may be needed, especially for graphical sessions

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tylerjl/overdue:

> Overdue is a pacman post-transaction hook that looks for running daemons that reference deleted shared library file handles and notifies you about them. It's a simple shell script that makes no changes to your system, and lists all relevant units for easy reference.

It uses `lsof` underneath, and it's currently available in the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/overdue/).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to compare the version of the running kernel to the latest kernel on disk. I found a [script](https://linux-audit.com/how-to-check-arch-linux-system-needs-reboot/) that can do that easily.

As I have several kernels installed, I modified the script to check only the one corresponding to the running kernel. For example, I currently have versions 4.9.79 and 4.14.16 installed and thus need to check /boot/vmlinuz-4.14-x86_64. Unfortunately this won't work when I start using version 5.1, so an update will be needed (replace 4 by 3) or I need to find a more robust way.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
NEXTLINE=0
FIND=""
CURRENT_KERNEL=`uname -r`
KERNEL_PATH="/boot/vmlinuz-${CURRENT_KERNEL:0:4}"
for I in `file $KERNEL_PATH*`; do
  if [ ${NEXTLINE} -eq 1 ]; then
    FIND="${I}"
    NEXTLINE=0
   else
    if [ "${I}" = "version" ]; then NEXTLINE=1; fi
  fi
done
    if [ ! "${FIND}" = "" ]; then
      if [ ! "${CURRENT_KERNEL}" = "${FIND}" ]; then
    echo "Boot required"
  else echo "No boot required"
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to update an answer here, in the latest few versions, I noticed that there is a dot which changes to a hyphen,on one of the commands:

```bash
$ pacman -Q linux | sed 's/linux //'
5.19.11.arch1-1
$ uname -r
5.19.11-arch1-1
```

So now I use:

```bash
$ pacman -Q linux | sed 's/linux //'
5.19.11.arch1.1

$ uname -r | tr '-' '.'
5.19.11.arch1.1
```

And then I set them to a variable and compare them as usually and already referred above:

```bash
s1=$(pacman -Q linux | sed 's/linux //')
s2=$(uname -r | tr '-' '.')

if [ "$s1" != "$s2" ]; then
    echo "Reboot is required."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script that creates the `/var/run/reboot-required` file like in Debian/Ubuntu as a pacman hook by copying `/usr/share/libalpm/hooks/90-mkinitcpio-install.hook` and renaming it to `90-reboot-required.hook`. Then create a script (example):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

touch /var/run/reboot-required
```

Call it `reboot-required`, make sure it is executable

```bash
chmod +x reboot-required
```

Put it in `/usr/share/libalpm/scripts/`, specify it in your custom hook by changing the exec line to:

```ini
Exec = /usr/share/libalpm/scripts/reboot-required
```

and then you can check if the file exists as needed:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]
then
    echo "Reboot required"
fi
```

This would help determine if a reboot is required for other packages than just the kernel itself

Answer (score -1):

`needrestart` exists to answer that question, so install it with `yay needrestart`.

```
needrestart 3.6 - Restart daemons after library updates.

Authors:
  Thomas Liske <thomas@fiasko-nw.net>

Copyright Holder:
  2013 - 2022 (C) Thomas Liske [http://fiasko-nw.net/~thomas/]

Upstream:
  https://github.com/liske/needrestart

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

Usage:

  needrestart [-vn] [-c <cfg>] [-r <mode>] [-f <fe>] [-u <ui>] [-bkl]

    -v      be more verbose
    -q      be quiet
    -m <mode>   set detail level
    e   (e)asy mode
    a   (a)dvanced mode
    -n      set default answer to 'no'
    -c <cfg>    config filename
    -r <mode>   set restart mode
    l   (l)ist only
    i   (i)nteractive restart
    a   (a)utomatically restart
    -b      enable batch mode
    -p          enable nagios plugin mode
    -f <fe> override debconf frontend (DEBIAN_FRONTEND, debconf(7))
    -t <seconds> tolerate interpreter process start times within this value
    -u <ui>     use preferred UI package (-u ? shows available packages)

  By using the following options only the specified checks are performed:
    -k          check for obsolete kernel
    -l          check for obsolete libraries
    -w          check for obsolete CPU microcode

    --help      show this help
    --version   show version information
```