# When should I restart my computer after an update?

Tags: package-management, upgrade

When I use a GUI updater, sometimes it says that my computer needs to be restarted.
But when I use `apt-get upgrade` for example, I can't find messages like this.

I saw [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75505/47335), so do I need to check manually which packages were updated?

Comment: See also [needrestart](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=needrestart) which will tell you which daemons need restart, and offer to restart them for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/92932/how-does-ubuntu-keep-track-of-the-system-restart-required-flag-in-motd): after updating with `apt-get`, you can check for the presence of `/var/run/reboot-required`. You didn't mention what operating system distribution you're using, so you may want to double check that your distribution does indeed behave this way.